# Compiler error when enforcing c++11 move semantics

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I distilled the code and ended up with the one below. Error is when inserting into a map...

Thanks to the person who marked down the question - hopefully he will be the first to answer it ;).

Seriously now, my point is: the fact that move is done on a "best effort" basis and that one cannot ensure it is used (as here with a naive delete) makes room for a lot of confusion. To me it's dodgy one has to provide a never used copy constructor body just to silence the compiler.

Of course, may be a bad play between the compiler and my stl. Leaving the people who live and breathe the C++ standard to clarify.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct FeedDataType
{
    FeedDataType() {};
    FeedDataType(FeedDataType&& ) = default;

#if 0
    // error: use of deleted function 'FeedDataType::FeedDataType(const FeedDataType&) - why?
    FeedDataType(const FeedDataType& ) = delete;
#else
    // Compiles ok but never called. But cannot mark it delete...
    FeedDataType(const FeedDataType& ) { cout << "Never called!" << endl; };
#endif
};

int main ()
{
    vector< FeedDataType > x;
    map<int, vector< FeedDataType > > mymap;
    mymap.insert( std::make_pair( 0, x ) );
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from /cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/vector:63:0,
             from play3.cpp:1:
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = FeedDataType; _Args = {const FeedDataType&}]':
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const FeedDataType*, std::vector<FeedDataType> >; _ForwardIterator = FeedDataType*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const FeedDataType*, std::vector<FeedDataType> >; _ForwardIterator = FeedDataType*]'
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:260:63:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const FeedDataType*, std::vector<FeedDataType> >; _ForwardIterator = FeedDataType*; _Tp = FeedDataType]'
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:310:9:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = FeedDataType; _Alloc = std::allocator<FeedDataType>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<FeedDataType>]'
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_pair.h:137:64:   required from 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&) [with _U1 = int; _U2 = std::vector<FeedDataType>&; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = std::vector<FeedDataType>]'
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_pair.h:273:72:   required from 'constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = std::vector<FeedDataType>&; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = std::vector<FeedDataType>; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type = int]'
play3.cpp:24:44:   required from here
/cs/insight_san/tools/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: use of deleted function 'FeedDataType::FeedDataType(const FeedDataType&)'
play3.cpp:13:9: error: declared here
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

There is a compiler error (g++ 4.7.2 on RedHat) I'd like to clarify.
What is all about: simply want to enforce the use of the move constructor only.

So I write:

```
FeedDataType(FeedDataType&& ) = default;
FeedDataType(const FeedDataType& ) = delete;
```

Alas, it doesn't compile (I'll spare you the full stack trace):

```
.../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: use of deleted function 'FeedDataType::FeedDataType(const FeedDataType&)'
```

Not being obvious where copy ctor required, I write a body for it to let the program core when used and then look at the stack trace:

```
FeedDataType(FeedDataType&& ) = default;
FeedDataType(const FeedDataType& ) { cerr << "Called" << endl; assert(false); }
```

Well, the program compiles and runs without entering the copy ctor code. So, if not used, why cannot the copy ctor be deleted? How can one be sure of what is being used?

Other thing that I don't get:

```
void FeedData::add( const FeedDataType & feedDataRow )
{
    // Is move used here? If not why not warn?
    some_vector.push_back( std::move(feedDataRow) );
}
```

This apparently uses the copy constructor. Would have been good having a warning/error from the compiler that move construction was not in use here? In large programs it would be easy to miss the const and believe that std::move would do the job. In fact, should have been a compiler error - feedDataRow is const, move construction from it should not be possible?

Using non-const reference appears to be better as the move constructor is used in that case. Or should one pass here by value?

I think the first issue is a compiler bug, but would like to be enlightened by someone who knows what was going on. I was thinking move semantics is easy but obviously need to do my homework. Looking for Mr. Meyers books on C++11 ;).

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: `std::vector` I believe stores elements by value and uses the copy constructor internally when push back is called. Now I'm guessing that you are wanting to avoid such a copy, but I'm not sure if this is permitted, to be honest I'm not very familiar with this area of c++11.

Comment: Did not the original compile-time stack trace (which you spared us) point to `FeedData::add`?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? You are trying to move from a const. This is not possible, so copying is tried instead. Copying is disabled, you get a compilation error. So far everything looks completely logical. Where's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Just because a particular program run doesn't enter your copy constructor, doesn't mean that your code doesn't call it somewhere.

Comment: @n.m. - There were 2 questions in my post. The first one, why compile error, still stands. For the second one, I admit, I should have read a bit in stackoverflow... Other people were asking the same, some proposed a new std::force_move() or similar. But I think it's a valid concern: say that by force of habit you pass as const& and then use move(). Without really good eyes or profiling someone would not know that an expensive copy is happening instead of a move. Some posts discuss this... started reading ;)...

Answer (score 1):

> Well, the program compiles and runs without entering the copy ctor code.
>   So, if not used, why cannot the copy ctor be deleted?
>   How can one be sure of what is being used?

It may be in a scope where it may be use

in the following code:

```
void foo() = delete;

void bar(bool b)
{
    if (b) { foo(); }
    // Other stuff
}
```

Suppose that we call only `bar(false)`, `foo` is not called, but `bar` use a deleted function anyway.

If you follow the error link, you will see in which part of code Copy Constructor may be used.

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` means, approximately, "move if you can, otherwise copy" (not quite, but close enough for purposes of this discussion). It does not mean "move if you can, otherwise panic". The former semantics is useful most everywhere, including virtually all situations of writing template-based generic components. The latter is only useful in rare cases when moving might be impossible, and copying might be possible, but you don't want to copy.

The standard gives you the former semantics but not the latter. If you need the latter, you can write your own along these lines:

```
template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& my_move( T&& t )
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
}

template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& my_move( const T& t )
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T&>::value, "Move is requested, but only copying is possible");
}
```

Comment: I see. But why wasn't it then named try_move or maybe_move? Or say it's a cast? In fact, it doesn't move by itself... like the remove algorithm that doesn't remove. Why one should one pick new C++ features + the standard + Meyers's books in order to be able to code. Don't get me wrong, I'm a c++ fan and admit people should read the manuals. Let's leave it here... On the other hand, I've edited my post to show where the problem. Looks like have to add a dummy body to silence the compiler. But what about the "you don't pay for what you don't use" principle? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor is used by the copy constructor of `vector`, which is used  by the constructor of `std::pair` called in `std::make_pair`. The reason it's not actually called in a given run of your little example program is that the vector is empty.

Try `std::move` on the `x` when you call `make_pair`.

Comment: Perfect, this is what was indeed needed! With move in the make_pair it compiles cleanly and no dodgy dummy copy constructors that not called but are required... So clear now, as usual after one opens your eyes. Thanks!